# Firewall allows only port 22 but I can still curl via http. Need help

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall, ufw

I am struggling to get the Ubuntu firewall working as desired.

I have set up a Database on an Ubuntu `20.04.3 LTS`. I would like to be able to block request such as `curl -G --data-urlencode "some_query_here" http://ip_address:port/something` from everywhere outside the server itself. So I do the following (on a clean ufw):

```
sudo ufw default deny incoming
sudo ufw default allow outgoing
sudo ufw allow ssh
```

which leaves me with:

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

however when I go on my terminal (not ssh'ed into the Ubunut server) and try `curl -G --data-urlencode "some_query_here" http://ip_address:port/something`, I still get a successful result. I was expected the firewall to block it.

Why is the firewall not blocking this and how can I make it block?

Comment: It's an *expected response* to your outbound cURL packets, not an unsolicited inbound connection attempt. That's normal firewall behavior.

Comment: Okay, can you please help me understand what the problem is and how can I fix it? @user535733

Comment: Look at it like this: You told the system to go fetch an URL. It did exactly that. It was smart enough to recognize the response to the query and to let that response through the firewall *because you asked for it*. If you tried instead an unsolicited connection to cURL, the system would say "Huh? That was not requested. I'm ignoring it."